# Team Foundation Error with the / in the path

Tags: tfs

After installing some packages using **npm** or **jspm**, I see errors like the following. Is there some settings for TFS to accept these invalid characters.

```
TF10122: The path '$/$.core.js' contains a '$' at the beginning of a path component. Remove the '$' and try again.
TF10122: The path '$/$.invoke.js' contains a '$' at the beginning of a path component. Remove the '$' and try again.
TF10122: The path '$/$.partial.js' contains a '$' at the beginning of a path component. Remove the '$' and try again.
TF10122: The path '$/$.to-object.js' contains a '$' at the beginning of a path component. Remove the '$' and try again.
TF10122: The path '$/$.to-iobject.js' contains a '$' at the beginning of a path component. Remove the '$' and try again.
TF10122: The path '$/$.object-to-array.js' contains a '$' at the beginning of a path component. Remove the '$' and try again.
```

Comment: Under what circumstances are you getting this error? During a build?

Comment: I see these errors when I run a command like **jspm install aurelia** in the powershell window inside the VS 2015.

Comment: In the case of Core-JS (most of the issues you'll have with Aurelia), note this bug: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/129
Hopefully will be resolved in the next major release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a `$` in your server path.

If you really *must* have a `$` in a filename then you can set up a working folder mapping from `$/acceptable-filename` to a local path of  `c:/$.to-object.js`.

(Note also that you should not just put files at the root of a repository.  Put them inside a team project.)

Comment: I have no control over these because these are npm and GitHub modules which are downloaded into my project by **jspm** package manager.

Comment: Then your only workaround is to map each of these files individually, so that the server path doesn't have a `$`